# Как сделать чтобы рандом не повторялся в телеграм боте?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
import random
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot("....")
```

Допустим есть функция

```
def random_text():
 array = ['Some text-1','Some text-2','Some text-3']
 return str( random.choice(array) )
```

Допустим есть бот

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def reaction(message):
  if message.chat.type == 'private':
     if message.text == 'Something':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, random_text())
```

Я пробовал сделать как-то так:

```
def random_text():
 array = ['Some text-1','Some text-2','Some text-3']
 choice = random.choice(array)
 array.remove(choice)
 return str(choice)
```

Но оно не работает.И если можно, то как обновить список после перечисления всех его элементов?

Comment: Что значит "обновить"?

Comment: Ну так как я удалял элементы из списка с помощью .remove.Хотелось чтобы при условии if not array:"Добавить все элементы назад"

Comment: Не стало понятнее. список всё равно создается заново при каждом вызове функции, что мешает создать его еще раз при любом условии?

Comment: Спасибо я это не учел